# which unix commands for monitoring disk operating are available?

Tags: command, disk, ssd

To do some tests on SSD disk, I need to monitor operations such as number of reads and writes, access timestamp, which address accessed, write policy and so on. I know there is these commands:

```
$ vmstat

$ blktrace
```

which other commands are available? I want a set of this type of commands to compare them and use the bests.

Comment: The man page for `vmstat` will point you to some other possible tools, in the _see also_ section at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the ssd 'test' actually means that you have to test and report the performance of the disk, I'd go for collectd.
It's a system performance statistics collection daemon, highly configurable, that has a [disk plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Disk).

There are multiple output options like CSV or RRDTool to make nice graphs if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the following:

- nmon
- glances.
- iotop

But they are linux tools, I don't know which operating systems you have in mind especially.